# Order Data using Pivot Function and Select specific columns on secondary table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm writing a stored proc to return data from ***different*** tables into a single row with respective to a specific order, which are the properties of the primary key.

I have a table as shown below. I think the following table should be queried using the `PIVOT` Function.

```
   *Category Table*
-----------------------
| OrderNo | Category |                 /********************************/
-----------------------                      Available Categories
| A0001   | T-Shirt  |                               T-Shirts
| A0001   | Shorts   |                               Shorts
| A0001   | HeadCap  |                               HeadCap
| A0002   | Pants    |                               Pants
| A0002   | Jackets  |                               Jackets
| A0002   | TankTops |                               TankTops
| A0002   | Shorts   |                               Bags
| A0003   | Pants    |
| A0003   | Jackets  |
| A0003   | Bags     |
-----------------------
```

Another Table contains the order Properties i.e., `OrderNo,ApprovedDate,TotalValue,Currency`

```
                  *Ord_Property Table*
------------------------------------------------------
| OrderNo | ApprovedDate | TotalValue | ShipmentType |
------------------------------------------------------
| A0001   | 11/19/2019   |   68.50    |   Ground    |
| A0002   | 11/07/2019   |   240.00   |   2-Day     |
| A0003   | 10/31/2019   |   180.00   |   Ground    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

**Output** - When I ran the query specific to the order number, I'm trying to find any output as follows with columns for all the available categories in Table 1, along with the selected columns from the second Table.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| OrderNo | ApprovedDate | TotalValue | ShipmentType | T-Shirt | Shorts | HeadCap | Pants | Jackets | TankTops | Bags |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A0001   | 11/19/2019   |   68.50    |   Ground     |    Y    |   Y    |    Y    |   N   |   N     | N        |  N   |
| A0002   | 11/07/2019   |   240.00   |   2-Day      |    N    |   Y    |    N    |   Y   |   Y     | Y        |  N   |
| A0003   | 10/31/2019   |   180.00   |   Ground     |    N    |   N    |    N    |   Y   |   Y     | N        |  Y   |
```

I tried `select * from the second table and inner joined the first table on the OrderNo column`. Along with the case statements in the Select list but the output is not as expected and instead of single row, it ends up Multiple columns.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
SELECT OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency 
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'T-Shirt' THEN 'T-Shirt' END AS 'Requires_T-Shirt'
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'Shorts' THEN 'Shorts' END AS 'Requires_Shorts'
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'HeadCap' THEN 'HeadCap' END AS 'Requires_HeadCap'
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'Pants' THEN 'Pants' END AS 'Requires_Pants'
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'Jackets' THEN 'Jackets' END AS 'Requires_Jackets'
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'TankTops' THEN 'TankTops' END AS 'Requires_TankTops'
     , CASE WHEN Category = 'Bags' THEN 'Bags' END AS 'Requires_Bags'
FROM Ord_Property OP
INNER JOIN Category C ON C.OrderNo = OP.OrderNo
WHERE OP.ORDERNO =  @OrderNo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'T-Shirt' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'T-Shirt'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Shorts' THEN 'Y'ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Shorts'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'HeadCap' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'HeadCap'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Pants' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Pants'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Jackets' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Jackets'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'TankTops' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END) AS 'TankTops'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Bags' THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N'END) AS 'Bags'
FROM Ord_Property OP
INNER JOIN Category C 
ON C.OrderNo = OP.OrderNo
WHERE OP.ORDERNO =  @OrderNo
GROUP BY OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency
```

Try this Query......

Here i'm using **CASE WHEN THEN Query**...If records match then **'Y'** else **'N'**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'T-Shirt' THEN 'T-Shirt' END) AS 'Requires_T-Shirt'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Shorts' THEN 'Shorts' END) AS 'Requires_Shorts'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'HeadCap' THEN 'HeadCap' END) AS 'Requires_HeadCap'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Pants' THEN 'Pants' END) AS 'Requires_Pants'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Jackets' THEN 'Jackets' END) AS 'Requires_Jackets'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'TankTops' THEN 'TankTops' END) AS 'Requires_TankTops'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Bags' THEN 'Bags' END) AS 'Requires_Bags'
FROM Ord_Property OP
INNER JOIN Category C 
    ON C.OrderNo = OP.OrderNo
WHERE OP.ORDERNO =  @OrderNo
GROUP BY OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

No need for `PIVOT` here. Simple **Aggregate(MAX)** will give the result.

```
SELECT C.OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'T-Shirt' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'T-Shirt'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Shorts' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Shorts'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'HeadCap' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'HeadCap'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Pants' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Pants'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Jackets' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Jackets'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'TankTops' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'TankTops'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Bags' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS 'Bags'
FROM Ord_Property OP
INNER JOIN Category C 
    ON C.OrderNo = OP.OrderNo
WHERE OP.ORDERNO =  @OrderNo
GROUP BY C.OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency
```

Answer (score 0):

it returned `multiple rows` because you have multiple `categories` joined

```
SELECT OrderNo, ApprovedDate, TotalValue ,Currency 
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'T-Shirt' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_T-Shirt'
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'Shorts' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_Shorts'
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'HeadCap' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_HeadCap'
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'Pants' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_Pants'
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'Jackets' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_Jackets'
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'TankTops' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_TankTops'
    , case when 
        (select 1 from Category t1 
            where t1.Category = 'Bags' and t1.orderNo = OP.OrderNo) = 1 
        then 'Y' else 'N' end AS 'Requires_Bags'     
FROM Ord_Property OP
WHERE OP.ORDERNO =  @OrderNo
```

You can also use **sqlserver** `iif` function

```
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'T-Shirt' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_T-Shirt'
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'Shorts' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_Shorts'
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'HeadCap' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_HeadCap'
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'Pants' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_Pants'
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'Jackets' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_Jackets'
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'TankTops' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_TankTops'
    , iif(max(iif(C.Category = 'Bags' and C.orderNo = OP.OrderNo, 1, 0)) = 1, 'Y', 'N') as 'Requires_Bags'
```